# Filter custom post type archive with product category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type based on Woocommerce product taxonomy. I would like to use these taxonomies to filter custom posts on the archive page.

I have read a lot of articles on this but could not achieve my goal.
So far I have created a new archive-mypost.php page and displayed all the customs posts and all the categories with the following code :

```
<div class="filter-custom-taxonomy">

     <?php
    $terms = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'] );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
    <a href="?getby=cat&cat=<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
                    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <?php do_action( 'thb_archive_title' ); ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'inc/templates/post-styles/post-style1' );
                    endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            the_posts_pagination(
                array(
                    'prev_text' => '',
                    'next_text' => '',
                    'mid_size'  => 2,
                )
            );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the filter does not work, when I click on a categories nothing happens.
Also I am still trying to figure out how to show only categories with results and hide the rest.

Thanks everyone !

Comment: Have you tried to use ?getby=cat&product_cat=<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?> URL format?

Comment: Not sure about the way to do that @Djanym but I tried to replace `<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>` by `<?php echo esc_attr( $term->url ); ?>` , it did not change anything

Comment: I have replaced by `<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/tutos/?getby=cat&cat=<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>">` which seems better and get me the URL with the category name, however it still does not filter my results and I do not get why

Answer (score 0):

I have figured part of the solution
This code works to display woocommerce categories on custom post archive page and filter results.

Only thing I do not know yet is to display only top categories first, then when the top category is selected, show subcategories

```
<div class="filter-custom-taxonomy">
<?php
$terms = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'] );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/tutos/?getby=cat&cat=<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>">
<?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
                
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <?php do_action( 'thb_archive_title' ); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'inc/templates/post-styles/post-style1' );
                endwhile;
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        the_posts_pagination(
            array(
                'prev_text' => '',
                'next_text' => '',
                'mid_size'  => 2,
            )
        );
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my function.php page :

```
function kbites_words_filter_archive( $query ) {
      if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
      return $query;
      if ( is_admin() ) {
              return;
      }
      if ( is_post_type_archive('tutos') ) {
        if (isset($_GET['getby'])) {
              if ( 'cat' === $_GET['getby'] ) {
                          $taxquery = array(
                                  array(
                                          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                          'field' => 'slug',
                                          'terms' => $_GET['cat'],
                                  ),
                          );
                          $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
              }
      }
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 30 );
    }
      return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'kbites_words_filter_archive');
```